# How can I download a webpage to a PDF in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, pdf

I am trying to find a way to download an URL and convert it into a PDF.

I have found lots of suggestions on how to turn PDFs into HTML or HTML into PDFs, but that's not the same as what I want to do.

Basically I am looking for the same result as if I had opened the page in {insert browser of choice} and selected "Print" and then PDF » Save as PDF…

But I want to be able to do it all from Terminal, automatically, so that I can feed it a handful of URLs at once and have it do it all for me.

I don't need or want recursion to additional pages.

> [Note: I have tried `wget --page-requisites --convert-links` but it does not always actually fetch images which are loaded from a remote server. Also, assume for this execs that the URLs are not behind any sort of login requirement.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

You can download the binary from that website. Note that you should change the file permissions to +x to make it executable.

For usage, check out http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/Usage or execute:

> wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368 --help

Comment: Yes! The static version (wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368) works perfectly, and includes working links (which the 'Homebrew' version does not). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is a new answer available which was not available when I asked this question: **Use Chrome**.

```
CHROME='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'

"$CHROME" --headless --print-to-pdf="$HOME/Documents/filename.pdf" "http://example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is [wkpdf](http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/) (webkit to pdf), but it´s broken under Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion).

You might also want to try [CutyCapt](http://blog.iharder.net/2010/01/05/command-line-capture-of-web-pages-to-pdf-png-svg-etc/), but that requires [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/qt-for-open-source-cpp-development-on-mac-os-x) and I haven´t tried that.